# Adding an SVG in React that fill its container div without Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to add an SVG image to my React project. If the device is small then the image looks fine but when the device is too big like 32 inches 4K then the height becomes too weird.

Here is the code

```
<div className="section-divider">
    <img src={MyCSV} alt="Your SVG" />
</div>
```

the css is here

```
.section-divider{
    width: 100%;
}

.section-divider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* object-fit: cover; */
}
```

for this, I am getting the following where the width is ok but the height is changing with the device as aspect ratio is not changing.
[image]

Now if I am adding `height: 100px;` to `section-divider`

```
.section-divider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.section-divider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* object-fit: cover; */
}
```

It is becoming like the following (Do not compare color)
[image]

If I use `object-fit: cover;` in image then the svg is filling the div but in scale like the following image

```
.section-divider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

[image]

I want its height always will be 100px and width 100% but SVG will fill its full area.